# date from string not working

Tags: objective-c, ios

CODE:

```
NSString* mydate = @"11/06/2012 19:15:40";
NSLog(@"%@", mydate);

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSDate* adate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:mydate];

NSLog(@"%@", adate);
```

LOG:

```
11/06/2012 19:15:40
(null)
```

Why am I getting null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date string is using slashes but your format specifier is setup to look for dashes.

Comment: If I tell you that I'm ripping my hair off for almost two hours on this. Can you believe it?

Comment: It's always the simple stuff. Here's a suggestion based on decades of coding. If you get stuck on anything for more than an hour - walk away. Do something else. Take a shower, go for a walk, work on something else. Clear your head. You'll be amazed how quickly you solve something after a break. And of course writing code is like proof reading your own paper. Get a 2nd pair of eyes. You know what you meant. It's easy to read something wrong over and over. Someone else can walk up and point out the issue in seconds.